# Codeigniter email class-not sending if 2 words are typed into Name field

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, email

Like tha title says, on my page i have a contact form with Email, Name and Message fields.
For some reason, if the 2 words are typed into Name field (for example "John Doe"), i get an error when i try to send it :\

Anybody have any suggestions?

```
public function send_mail($res)
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol'] = 'SMTP';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.something.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'email@something.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '25';

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from($res['sender_name'], $res['sender_email']);
        $this->email->to($res['reciever']);
        $this->email->reply_to($res['sender_email'], $res['sender_name']);

        $this->email->subject('Message from website');
        $this->email->message($res['message']);

        if($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        //configure mail agent...
    }

    private function get_email_address($email)
    {
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $email = $this->main_model->get_email($email);
        return $email;
    }

    public function get_email_message()
    {
        //only ajax requests are allowed
        if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            die();
        }
        $res['message'] = $this->input->post('message');
        $res['reciever'] = $this->input->post('receiver');
        $res['sender_name'] = $this->input->post('sender_name');
        $res['sender_email'] = $this->input->post('sender_email');

        $res['reciever'] = $this->get_email_address($res['reciever']);

        $res = $this->send_mail($res);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($res));
    }
```

P.S I found this JS code that looks to be for errors and validation, dont know does it help :\

```
function createEmailElem() {
    var parentElem = document.getElementById('contact_art');
    var messageElem = document.createElement('textarea');
    messageElem.id = 'email_message';
    messageElem.style.cssText = "float:right;width: 93%;box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;height:100px;";
    //messageElem.id = "email_mess";
    //messageElem.attributes.placeholder = 'Poruka';
    //$('#email_mess').attr('placeholder') = 'test';
    var nameDiv = document.createElement('div');
    nameDiv.style.marginBottom = '5px';
    var emailDiv = document.createElement('div');
    emailDiv.style.marginBottom = '5px';

    var labelMessage = document.createElement('label');
    labelMessage.innerHTML = 'Poruka';
    var labelName = document.createElement('label');
    labelName.innerHTML = 'Vaš e-mail';
    labelName.style.marginRight = '5px';
    var labelEmail = document.createElement('label');
    labelEmail.innerHTML = 'Vaše ime';
    labelEmail.style.marginRight = '10px';


    var nameElem = document.createElement('input');
    nameElem.type = "text";
    nameElem.name = "sender_name";
    nameElem.id = "sender_name";

    var emailElem = document.createElement('input');
    emailElem.type = "text";
    emailElem.name = "sender_email";
    emailElem.id = "sender_email";

    var buttonElem = document.createElement('input');
    buttonElem.className = 'gradient-button';
    buttonElem.id = 'email_send';
    buttonElem.type = 'button';
    buttonElem.value = 'Posalji';
    buttonElem.style.cssText = "margin-top:10px;float: right;"

    nameDiv.appendChild(labelName);
    nameDiv.appendChild(nameElem);

    emailDiv.appendChild(labelEmail);
    emailDiv.appendChild(emailElem);

    parentElem.appendChild(nameDiv);
    parentElem.appendChild(emailDiv);
    parentElem.appendChild(labelMessage);
    parentElem.appendChild(messageElem);
    parentElem.appendChild(buttonElem);
}

/*if email not found*/
function createNoticeElem() {
    var parentElem = document.getElementById('contact_art');
    var messageElem = document.createElement('p');
    messageElem.innerHTML = 'The user didn\'t leave the e-mail address';
    parentElem.appendChild(messageElem);
}

function sendEmail() {
    if(ckeckEmail()) {
        createEmailElem();
    } else {
        createNoticeElem();
    }
}

function sendingSuccess() {
    var parentElem = document.getElementById('contact_art');
    var messageElem = document.createElement('p');
    messageElem.innerHTML = 'Email was sended succesfuly!';
    parentElem.appendChild(messageElem);
}

function sendingError() {
    var parentElem = document.getElementById('contact_art');
    var messageElem = document.createElement('div');
    messageElem.className = 'alert alert-error';
    messageElem.innerHTML = 'Error! Email was not sended!';
    messageElem.style.width = '150px';
    parentElem.appendChild(messageElem);
}

function phpSendingError() {
    var parentElem = document.getElementById('contact_art');
    var messageElem = document.createElement('div');
    messageElem.className = 'alert alert-error';
    messageElem.style.width = '250px';
    messageElem.innerHTML = 'Error! Email was not sended! Something wrong with server';
    parentElem.appendChild(messageElem);
}
```

Comment: Strange ! what error did you get?

Comment: Im not really an expert in PHP, so i dont know where to check for this, but you can see the example here : http://goo.gl/uLNRv
Try typing something in the name field (one word) and it will send, but if 2 words are typed...Error "Error! Email was not sended!"

Comment: its giving same message even name is entered as a single word. Did u receive mail or it's javascript throwing error messages ?

Comment: If 2 words are typed, i dont get any email, just that "Error! Email was not sended!" message :\

Comment: I entered single word but still get same error message. are you sure, you received mail when single word is entered?

Comment: From what i found out while testing (trying tons of combinations of messages and emails), error is only shown if 2 words are typed in Name field, and if visitor used email from domain that doesnt exist (for example "something@sdjkfnsjdnfjks.com)...
Very very weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [other way round](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html):

```
$this->email->from($res['sender_email'], $res['sender_name']);
```

You accidently misplaced the attributes. The same applies to your form labels.

```
…&sender_name=mrabe%40example.com&sender_email=Marvin+Test
```

The values are transferred wrong.

If you use an email address that is not from your server then the SMTP server could prohibit sending. The server is using the [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework). Replace the email address in `from()` by an address that is an real email from your server or append .

Comment: Actually, i made it otherway around, since i couldnt send the email the way it was :\
This way, email is sent properly, but only if there is one word in "Name" field....

Comment: Can you send an email with _John Doe_ and _something@yourserver.com_ ? _yourserver.com_ has to be the real domain of the server.

Comment: Just tried it, no luck, same thing happens :\ I used my email at this domain where the site, plus one of my old emails at my own domain, and nothing, same thing ...

Comment: Got it. You misplaced name and email multiple times. The labels of your form are wrong. If you type your email address in your name field and the name into the email field everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry, i have been googling my ass the last 30 mins :\
Im PHP rookie, somebody else developed this for me, is there any chance that you could help me and tell me what to replace with what? 
P.S Got your email

Comment: No problem. Will help you on friday (tomorrow is Valantinesday ;-) )… Just send me an email.

Comment: Only that?I planned to give you my kidney or something xD